# Red x on windows user

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, user

I have the same issue as [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/459174/folder-permissions-red-x-on-user-object) serverfault question. My question is what does the red cross on the user mean? In my case he is the administrator. How do I remove the red cross. I restarted the computer removed the user and added the user back and the red sign still shows up. I am actually getting an error in my application because of this who does not have proper access to the folder I am trying to access.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK this is what I have done so far which kind of fixes the above problem. But my application still has problem.

Go to start, right click on my computer and select manager. In the Computer Management Window, select Local User and Group node on the left side. Select users. Select the user that you are having problem with. Right click and properties. Then uncheck the check mark "Account is disabled".

The above step did not cleanly removed the red check. I also did the same for Aministrator account which also had the check mark. Then I had to restart the computer to see the changes.

While this has remove the red check, I am still having issues with IIS which I guess is a separate issue (but related).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post but...

I had this problem also, adding the Domain Administrator account to a share and applying Full Control.  From another server the account was denied access to the share and a Red X could be seen on the icon as show in the original post.

What I did to resolve it was to add the Domain Admins Group to the permissions list instead of the user.  I guess you could alternatively ensure that the Domain Administrator is in the Local Administrators Group and use that one instead if you'd prefer not to use the Domain group?

There was no need for a restart or anything, the Administrator was able to immediately access the share from a remote computer.